# Getting results of a MongoDB query to use in a select menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a website that allows you to search for people in a database based on location. Initially, the dropdown menu (select) is populated with provinces that available people are in. I'm trying to use a mongo query to populate that select menu. But when I try to get the values outside the function, it does not work and the select menu turns up empty.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
  
const Locations = () => {

  let options = null;

  function axiosTest() {
    // This is a server link i created that runs a query that returns distinct provinces from the database
    const promise = axios.get("/api/v2/people/provinces");
    const dataPromise = promise.then(result => result.data).then(data => {console.log(data);return data;});
    // The console.log() above displays all the objects that are in the query given by the server link in an array
    // e.g. ['British Columbia', 'Alberta', 'Saskatchewan', etc.]
  }
  
  var type = axiosTest();
  console.log(type);  // now it displays it as "undefined"

  if (type) {
    options = type.map((el) => <option key={el}>{el}</option>);
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: "16px",
        margin: "16px",
      }}
    >
      <form>
        <div>
          <select>
            {
              /** This is where we have used our options variable */
              options
              // and the select menu is shown as blank, because it doesn't have any options to fill it with
            }
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
  
export default Locations;
```

Can someone please help me get this to work? Is it something to do with Threads and Concurrency? I'm unfortunately rusty at that.

Answer (score 0):

Function `axiosTest()` does not return anything. You should specify change your code so the function would return the result of DB query. You can also change `.then()` syntax with `async/await` so your code would become more readable.

```js
const Locations = async () => {

  let options = null;

  function axiosTest() {
    return axios.get("/api/v2/people/provinces");
  }
  
  var type = await axiosTest();
  console.log(type); 

  ...

};
```

Comment: When I try to add "async" to the const Locations line, it gives me this:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How do I fix this?